# How to print out longest increasing subsequence by recursion

Tags: recursion, lis

Given a sequence of n integer stored in an array, describe a recursive algorithm to print out a subsequence of non-decreasing elements with maximum length. A subsequence may contain non-consecutive elements but they should be ordered in the same way as the original sequence.

Please help me :(

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a program that is not working. There is no program at all.

Comment: this is my homework :(

Comment: "[Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" Make sure to check your school's academic honesty policy regarding external assistance on homework. At a minimum, you will probably need to cite any Web site you obtained assistance from. (Otherwise, it would be plagiarism.)

Comment: This is not homework for me and its not answered very well any where on the internet. As is often with stackoverflow this unanswered question is the on the first page of google search for "print recursive longest increasing subsequence"